# XML validation issue with DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm a new for XML and learning my first course right now.

What I have got the error is: when I validate my XML file it shows:

> markup declaration expected

**My XML and Internal DTD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"   standalone="yes"?>
<!-- This is Internal DTD-->
<!DOCTYPE employee[
<!DOCTYPE head (title)>
<!DOCTYPE title EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT employee (body,details)+>
<!ELEMENT details (name, address, d_o_birth, d_o_join, phone, desig, dept, e_mail*)>
<!ELEMENT name EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST  name gender (male | female) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT address EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT d_o_birth EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT d_o_join EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT phone (resi,mobile)>
<!ELEMENT resi EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT mobile EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT desig EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT dept EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT e_mail (#PCDATA)>
]>

<employee>
    <head>
          <title>Employee Details</title>

    </head>
<body>
            <details>
                      <name>Name:         Ismail Kedir
                                      Gender:      Male</name>
                      <address>:                Jima, Kochi</address>
                      <d_o_birth>:              27/9/1976</d_o_birth>
                      <d_o_join>:               03/10/2005</d_o_join>
                <phone>
                        <resi>:                       2352</resi>
                        <mobile>:               +251910178976</mobile>                
                </phone>
                <desig>:                          Teacher</desig>
                <dept>:                           JIT</dept>
                <e_mail>Email:            nur_selam@yahoo.com</e_mail>
            </details>
</body>
</employee>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that error because you have `DOCTYPE` declarations inside of your internal subset (between the `[` and `]`). They should be `ELEMENT` declarations (for the `head` and `title` elements).

However, that error is just the tip of the iceberg. I also noticed the following issues (there might be more):

- `details` is in the content model for `employee`, but should be in the content model for `body`.
- `body` needs to be declared.
- The following elements should be `#PCDATA` instead of `EMPTY`: `name`, `title`, `address`, `d_o_birth`, `d_o_join`, `resi`, `mobile`, `desig` and `dept`.
- The attribute `gender="male"` should be added to `name` in the instance (XML data itself).
- `title` should be `#PCDATA` instead of `EMPTY`.
- I would also recommend cleaning up the `#PCDATA`. You shouldn't need all of the labels (like `Gender:`, `Name:`, `Email:` and the other extraneous `:`). That seems to me more like presentation that would be handled by whatever system is consuming the XML.

Here's a valid version that should get you started. (I did not do any data cleanup.)

```
<?xml version="1.0"   standalone="yes"?>
<!-- This is Internal DTD-->
<!DOCTYPE employee [
<!ELEMENT head (title)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT employee (head,body)>
<!ELEMENT body (details)>
<!ELEMENT details (name, address, d_o_birth, d_o_join, phone, desig, dept, e_mail*)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST name gender (male | female) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT d_o_birth (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT d_o_join (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT phone (resi,mobile)>
<!ELEMENT resi (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT mobile (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT desig (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT dept (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT e_mail (#PCDATA)>
]>
<employee>
    <head>
        <title>Employee Details</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <details>
            <name gender="male">Name:         Ismail Kedir
                Gender:      Male</name>
            <address>:                Jima, Kochi</address>
            <d_o_birth>:              27/9/1976</d_o_birth>
            <d_o_join>:               03/10/2005</d_o_join>
            <phone>
                <resi>:                       2352</resi>
                <mobile>:               +251910178976</mobile>                
            </phone>
            <desig>:                          Teacher</desig>
            <dept>:                           JIT</dept>
            <e_mail>Email:            nur_selam@yahoo.com</e_mail>
        </details>
    </body>
</employee>
```

Comment: Really very helpful and smart answer.